# GA4 Internal Traffic filter not appearing in comparision dropdown in real-time overview

Tags: google-analytics-4

Following the GA4 documentation for setting up internal traffic identification via Tag Manager and then creating a Data Filter to filter page_view per traffic_type property I thought that I can go to my real-time overview and toggle the filter from the comparison dropdown.

However, `Test data filter name` is greyed out and the hover over message says "No data currently available for this dimension". I created this filter about 3 hours ago. I know that that the traffic_type property is registering on page_view events because I can see this with the preview functionality in Google Tag Manager when I navigate across my site with the "excluded" internal IP.

The docs make it seem like this comparison will be available on creation. Should I expect this? Or should I expect some sort of 24 hour delay like creating a conversation?

Comment: Can you share the detail about how you set it up? If you have the IP address rule, you can just set it on the GA4 admin.

Comment: I followed this article step-by-step: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10104470?hl=en

Comment: Worked. Just re-saved the data filter perimeter value. Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Actually, whenever I open up my comparison dropdown from any report the "Test data filter name" takes a while to load. Until it loads the section is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's "normal" for GA4 that custom or built-in dimensions sometimes aren't available in Comparisons. It can be a temporary bug or you just need to wait a day or two to gather enough data.
Also, if you're using Google Signals as the GA4 Reporting Identity, dimensions with a low count of occurrences may be omitted from the reports altogether.

But what's even worse, using IP addresses for recognizing internal traffic only works for static IP addresses, like office buildings and such. If you want to track internal users as accurately as possible, this would need to include people working from home and even their personal mobile devices.

I had an idea of a much better method for [GA4 internal traffic filtering](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/filtering-internal-traffic-ga4-self-id-without-ip-addresses-basrak).
There's the full rundown.